# Backbone save with LocalStorage with fetched DB data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

UPDATE

Ok, so I am still getting into the world of Backbone. But I have an issue with adding in localStorage into the Model.

So this is sorta off working, but I do not know what is going on?

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeCollection"),
    url: "/GetMyData",
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "datatest1": "",
        "test2": ""
    }
});

var NewTest = new Model();
NewTest.fetch();

console.log ( NewTest ); //This as DB data
console.log ( NewTest.attributes ); //This is empty
```

How can the 'attributes' on the 1st console.log contain db data and then the second one be completely empty? The 1st console.log is also empty, if I uncomment the localStorage, so I am guesting I doing something wrong?

---

Ok, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am using Backbone and on a fetch call, save that id using the LocalStorage plugin. Now I have the fetch call and LocalStorage working apart but can not get them working together.

So my LocalStorage Code

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeCollection"),
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "datatest1": "",
        "test2": ""
    }
});

var NewTest2 = new Model();

NewTest2.set({
    "id": "99",
    "datatest1": "TEST-1-Q22",
    "test2": "TEST-2-CL22"
});

NewTest2.save();
```

So this works, no problems with that. Now I add in a collection, and fetch data form my database. So my fetch code, with collection

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "datatest1": "",
        "test2": ""
    }
});

var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model,
    url: "/GetMyData"
});

var NewTest3 = new Col();

NewTest3.fetch();

console.log( NewTest3 );
```

I should also say that I am using PHP Slim as the base. The `/GetMyData` path gets the data from a MySQL database via a PDO connection, which I then convert into a JSON object for Backbone.

Which I assume is good, as that all works, the `console.log`'s list of attributes displays the right data form my DB.

Now when I put the two together, I can not seem to get it to work.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "datatest1": "",
        "test2": ""
    }
});

var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("SomeCollection2"),
    model: Model,
    url: "/GetMyData"
});

var NewTest4 = new Col();
NewTest4.fetch();

console.log( NewTest4.save() );
```

This `console.log` returns, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. So I am not sure why? When I set the data in my 1st test, it works fine. Now I have also tried moving the `localStorge` var into the model but with the same effect.

The main aim for doing this is so I can log all the data coming from the server. When I set a few different data tests, I very much like the way in which this plugin saved the data.

Thanks.

*Please note, I am dyslexic, so I may not have explained myself right, please tell me if there is anything I can re-word to explain myself better. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: `Backbone.Collection`, with or without `LocalStorage`, does not have a `save` method hence an `undefined` error. But that's not what you use in your previous tests, so is that what you intended to do?

Comment: @nikoshr updated my question, but I have noted that I should not call save on a BB collection, so I want to try and remove it, but I am getting an issue.